# Как работает downcasting?

Tags: java

У меня есть 2 класса C1 и C2  (C2 наследует C1).
Явным образом С1 привести к C2 я привести не могу:

```
C2 l = (C2) new C1(5);
```

Но можно так:

```
C2 c2 = new C2(5);

C1 c1 = c2;

C2 c21 =(C2) c1;
```

Вопрос: когда мы ссылке на класс C1 присваиваем значение ссылки c2  - это понятно, дочерний класс может "сузиться" до родительского. Но когда мы присваиваем ссылке с21 приведённую к С2 ссылку на класс C1 почему такое приведение срабатывает, ведь у нас с1 это по сути ссылка на родительский класс, как он может "расшириться" до дочернего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае *во время исполнения* выбрасывается `ClassCastException`, так как был создан экземпляр *родительского* класса, который нельзя присвоить классу-потомку, так как у такого экземпляра нет функционала требуемого класса-потомка.

А во втором случае имеется реально созданный экземпляр класса-потомка `C2`, поэтому "обратное" приведение типа от предка к потомку `C2 c21 = (C2) c1;` отработает корректно.